# How to pass schema name and table name as input then get memory size and row_count as output in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that returns row count and size of table(in bytes) dynamically.
What I want is pass schema and table name as a input then get memory size and row count for output.Here is my code :

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure get_table_count4 (table_name IN varchar2,schema_name IN varchar2
)
is
  table_count number;
  byte_count number;
  
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || table_name into table_count;
  dbms_output.put_line(table_count);
  select bytes from dba_segments into byte_count 
  where owner = schema_name and segment_name = UPPER(table_name);
  dbms_output.put_line(byte_count);

end;
```

I get this ERROR:

```
Procedure GET_TABLE_COUNT4 compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
10/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/34     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL komutu tam doğru olarak sona ermedi
Errors: check compiler log

Procedure GET_TABLE_COUNT4 compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
10/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/34     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not ended properly
Errors: check compiler log
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: just change the order of the clauses `into` and `from` so as to be `into byte_count from user_segments` rather than `from dba_segments into byte_count` as in the current state.

Comment: Approximate rowcount can be retrieved without any access to the table itself, because if your database is healthy, you already have up-to-date statistics and may consume it. Approximate table size can also be calculated from it by multiplying number of blocks by block size

Comment: Beware of SQL injection. Code you wrote won't prevent it.

Comment: Just to comment on terminology, dba_segments reports space used (storage), not memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly using COUNT(), but NUM_ROWS should do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_COUNT4(TABLE_NAME  IN VARCHAR2,
                                             SCHEMA_NAME IN VARCHAR2) IS
  TABLE_COUNT NUMBER;
  BYTE_COUNT  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT DB.NUM_ROWS
    INTO TABLE_COUNT
    FROM DBA_TABLES DB
   WHERE DB.TABLE_NAME = UPPER(TABLE_NAME);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_COUNT);

  SELECT BYTES
    INTO BYTE_COUNT
    FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
   WHERE OWNER        = UPPER(SCHEMA_NAME)
     AND SEGMENT_NAME = UPPER(TABLE_NAME);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(BYTE_COUNT);
END;
/
```

Comment: Good answer. But slight change needed in both queries, since data dictionary tables are all upper case and multiple schema may contain the same table name use:  `where owner = upper(schema_name) and <NAME> = upper(table_name)` replacing <NAME> with table_name or segment_name as appropriate.